# Android Firebase steps for implementing FCM (firebase cloude messageing) between users (user to user communication)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm checking this Firebase documentation and I'm not sure how to send FCM betwen users. I accomplish to send FCM from Firebase console to all users, and to one user (to me lol) by copy/paste token this way:

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

What I want is make a simple app where users have option to type some message and send it via FCM to some other specific user, not to everyone.

If I understand well, I need to do steps like these:

1. Set authentication like (like gogole sign in, facebook sign in...)
2. Get user token after sign in and send it to Firebase DB
3. Write Cloud Functions for Firebase in Google server where will pick up tokens from Firebase DB and then (as I read, it is possible to do this without app server but it is danger and not recommend)
4. Cloud Functions for Firebase will organize communication between users.

I know that lots of things are missing. So can you give me detailed steps how to do this. This is the first time I'm trying to use Firebase, so more detailed steps will help me to know what i need to learn to implement this.

Also, if there is some good link where I can learn this, it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You are already on the right track. And this detailed post in Github wiki of codepath will provide you what you need.

[Here is the link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is really helpful. If i understand well, on the link they make SQL database. Is it possible to do this without me making SQL database. Maybe im wrong but i if i understand well this is possible using new Firebase feature called Cloude Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/    Is it possible?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's another way to do it.

Comment: Do you have idea what steps would be to use firebase cloude function for sending user to user FCM.